# Khmer Unicdoe is not rendering properly

Tags: asp.net, itext

I am using dotnet core 3.1 with this https://github.com/VahidN/iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core/tree/master/src/iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core.FunctionalTests/iTextExamples

[image]

```
private Font GetFont(string fontNameWithExtension, int fontSize = 12)
        {
            // string fontLocation = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{"/wwwwroot/fonts/" + fontNameWithExtension}";
            string path = _webHostEnviroment.WebRootPath + "/fonts";
            string fontPath = Path.Combine(path, fontNameWithExtension);

            iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(fontPath);

            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            Font f = new Font(bf, fontSize);


            return f;
        }
```

Comment: iText 5 didn't have proper Khmer support. For that you'd have to go to iText 7 + pdfCalligraph.

Comment: how to do? it seemed complex

Comment: it's probably the simplest iText product. You just have it as a dependency, and if Core needs it, it will just use it. There's no API or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the font used in here: https://github.com/Seuksa/iTextKhmer/tree/master/src/main/resources

The fonts here have made special for case related to itext.